# ¿Cómo puedo obtener todos los id separados por coma?

Tags: php

Tengo 15 alumnos registrados en la tabla `alumnos`

De la siguiente consulta:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM alumnos");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
  $stmt->bind_result($id);
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //
  }
  $stmt->close();
}
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener todos los id de los alumnos separados por coma menos el ultimo id?

Mostrar este resultado

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto se puede realizar haciendo uso de [implode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) , pero antes debería obtener los valores en un `array`.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM alumnos");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$resultado = []; //Array 
if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
$stmt->bind_result($id);
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $resultado[] = $id; // Añadimos el id al array
  }
  $stmt->close();
  echo implode($resultado,','); // resultado final
}
else echo "No hay Resultados";
```

Answer (score 3):

Si solo vas a utilizar el id te puedes apoyar en fetch_all() para obtener todos los resultados devueltos  y en implode para unirlos por comas.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM alumnos");
$stmt->execute();

// Recuperar resultados
if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {
    // Optener filas como array númerico
    $idsArray = $result->fetch_all();
    // Optener primera columna del array y unirlos con comas 
    $idsComas = implode(array_column($idsArray, 0),',');
}

$stmt->close();

print_r($idsComas);
// Ejemplo resultado
// 1,3,5,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
```

Comment: como es que has puesto la respuesta como "wiki" ?

Comment: @Xerif Me muestra un fatal error: ***Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on boolean in*** `$idsArray = $result->fetch_all();`

Comment: @lois6b pues ni me di cuenta.

Comment: @Xerif y el error? Tienes un voto positivo deberías especificar porque el error? No veo ningún cambio que hayas realizado en el código.

Comment: @J.Doe ya esta corregido el error en la última edición, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Una vez que tienes los resultados de tu consulta en un array:

```
<?php

/**
 * Array con los registros 
 * ¡ojo! he duplicado y desordenado registros, luego veras porque
 *
 * @var        array
 */
$arr = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Foo',
        'email' => 'foo@mail.com',
    ],

    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Foo',
        'email' => 'foo@mail.com',
    ],

    [
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Xxx',
        'email' => 'xxx@mail.com',
    ],

    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Baz',
        'email' => 'baz@mail.com',
    ],

];

/**
 * Obtener array sólo con las ids
 *
 */
$arr_ids = array();
foreach( $arr as $row ) {

    $arr_ids[] = $row[ 'id' ];
}

/**
 * Si tu consulta fue compleja y devuelve filas duplicadas
 * puedes filtrar las ids repetidas
 * 
 */
$arr_ids = array_unique( $arr_ids );
//Ver: http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php

/**
 * Si tu consulta fue compleja y quieres tener las ids en orden
 * 
 */
sort( $arr_ids );
//Ver: http://php.net/manual/es/function.sort.php


/**
 * Convertir a un string, sepatando las ids por comas
 * 
 */
$str_ids = implode( ',', $arr_ids );
//Ver: http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php

/**
 * Resultado
 * 
 */
die( $str_ids ); //1,2,5
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa Mysql para lo que necesitas GROUP_CONCAT.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) 'ids' FROM alumnos");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
  $stmt->bind_result($ids);
  if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $ids;
  }
  $stmt->close();
}
```